# Washer and Condensing Dryer Share the Same Drain?

Tags: drain, dryer, washing-machine

Just moved to Germany again.  I want to buy a new washer and condensing dryer.  The Germans laundry rooms are all the same.  The washer discharge hose connects (screws) onto fitting on the wall.  I don't know the correct terminology or type, but I know it screws on, just like the water input hose.   I am tired of emptying the reservoir on the dryer and now see that every condensing dryer has the ability to use an accessory hose to discharge the water (just like I had in the USA).  But in the USA, the apartment was built with two drains.  How can get my new washer and dryer to share the same drain here in Germany?  There is no sink or floor drain in the apartment.  Its like I need a "Y" adapter where the two hoses can be joined and then connect into a single stream.  Does such a thing exist?  Surely I am not the first person who wants to do this. The accessory hose on the dryer is not threaded.  And then would I need some kind of check valve to prevent either machine from sending water into the other? Help.

Comment: Probably does exist, but the local rules and regulations will say what you can do by yourself.   Accessory hose might need an adapter.  Check valves should only be needed for a T, probably not for a Y pointing down.

Comment: Thx.  I'll keep you posted and see what happens on the install from the place I buy it.  Maybe the guys will know how to make it happen or I might have to get creative at the hardware store....or just empty the resevoir like everyone else in Germany.   It just seems so silly that nobody is bothered by the hassle of lugging 10lbs of water to the sink in the kitchen every other load of laundry.

Comment: Lug only 5 lbs every load while cleaning the lint filter. ;^)